# UIViewController not adjusting correctly in UIScrollView for all iPhones

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, frame

I am trying to replicate a Tinder like menu, with the 3 `UIViewControllers` in a `UIScrollView` and a custom menu tab on the top, with a button for each `UIViewController`. I am facing an interesting problem where the `UIViewControllers` views fit perfectly in the scrollView.frame, but only for iPhone 8. In contrast, for iPhone SE, it leaves a white margin and for iPhone 8+, it seems to overlap the views within the scrollView.view. Could someone explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Here's my code where I'm adjusting setting up my `UIViewControllers` in my `UIScrollView`:

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var navigationView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpHorizontalScrollViews()
    }

    func setUpHorizontalScrollViews(){

        let view = (
            x: self.view.bounds.origin.x,
            y: self.view.bounds.origin.y,
            width: self.view.bounds.width,
            height: self.view.bounds.height
        )

        let scrollWidth  = 3 * view.width
        let scrollHeight  = view.height
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollWidth, height: scrollHeight)
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = view.x

        if let messagesView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessagesVC") as UIViewController! {
            self.addChildViewController(messagesView)
            self.scrollView.addSubview(messagesView.view)
            messagesView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
            messagesView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                             y: 0,
                                             width: view.width,
                                             height: view.height
            )
        }


        if let friendsView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FriendsVC") as UIViewController! {
            self.addChildViewController(friendsView)
            self.scrollView.addSubview(friendsView.view)
            friendsView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
            friendsView.view.frame = CGRect(x: view.width,
                                            y: 0,
                                            width: view.width,
                                            height: view.height
            )
        }


        if let settingsView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsVC") as UIViewController! {
            self.addChildViewController(settingsView)
            self.scrollView.addSubview(settingsView.view)
            settingsView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
            settingsView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 2 * view.width,
                                             y: 0,
                                             width: view.width,
                                             height: view.height
            )
        }

        // offset to the second view
        self.scrollView.contentOffset.x = view.width

    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

This is what my Setup looks like. the top is the MainViewController, containing the `UIScrollView` and on bottom are the 3 viewcontrollers that are supposed to go into the scrollView.
[image]

This is what I want it to look like, and the way it sets up in iPhone 8:
[image]

This is what it looks like on iPhone SE and where my problem is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that since you are calling the `setUpHorizontalScrollViews` method in the `viewDidLoad()`, the UIViewController has yet to layout the subview, and also calculate their final size.

It is working in an iPhone 8 because most provably it has the same screen size you used in the interface builder.

**Solution 1**

In order to solve the problem, you can move your code to the `viewDidAppear()` method. However, this will cause an ugly effect once you open the UIViewController (unless you add a full screen loading).

**Solution 2**

Add `view.layourIfNeeded()` like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.layourIfNeeded()
    setUpHorizontalScrollViews()
}
```

Comment: that worked, thanks for the explanation, I was not aware of that. I chose to go with the viewDidAppear() option as the code is cleaner -> no ugly effect though